# Detecting outliers in a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a sample series which I am including here for reproducible example:

```
data = np.array([190, 1, 470, 183, 131, 0, 333, 14, 82, 31])
ser = pd.Series(data, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
```

I have written a function to detect outliers in this series with the following code:

```
def detect_outliers(data):
    q1, q3 = np.percentile(data, [25, 75])
    iqr = q3 - q1

    lower_bound = q1 - (iqr * 1.5)
    upper_bound = q3 + (iqr * 1.5)
    return np.where((data > upper_bound) > (data < lower_bound))
```

When I run this code on my series ***ser***, I get the following output:

[image]

I understand that this is referring to the data point with value 470 i.e. the ***3rd row*** (index=2). How can I get it to output the index 'C' instead of index 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the return like this

```
data[(data > upper_bound) > (data < lower_bound)]
```

Output:

```
c    470
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def detect_outliers(data):
    ls = []
    q1, q3 = np.percentile(data, [25, 75])
    iqr = q3 - q1

    lower_bound = q1 - (iqr * 1.5)
    upper_bound = q3 + (iqr * 1.5)
    return data[(data > upper_bound) > (data < lower_bound)]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.